# How can I send information to the console in vs2012 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I would like to log some data when I am in a for loop. How can I have the data sent to the VS2012 console so I can view it later?

Comment: What kind of application your are developing? Windows Forms or Console Application?

Comment: Did `Console.WriteLine()` change in VS2012?  I think that would be a big deal if it did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>what exactly do you mean? Would `Console.WriteLine(...)` do? Have you considered reading the documentation?</s>

Update: if output for debugging purposes in the actual VS console/shell is meant, one can set actions on breakpoints (at least in VS2017):

setting an action (right click):
[image: setting an action on a breakpoint]
In VS2013 it's called `When hit`

output action:
[image: adding and output action]

formatted output in the output console
[image: formatted output]